# How To Get Error After Compile Exe With Command Line In VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, command

I have Command in my program Like this:

`Shell " \Vb6 /MAKE "Project"`

How do I get error status of 
the command if the project contains errors ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `/out filename` to specify a file to receive error messages when building using `/make`.

Hint: if you run `VB6 /?` it will display the possible command-line flags. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The shell function can return a value.

Try:

```
 result = shell(".....
```